# How to add a correction to the personal dictionary

Tags: macos, catalina, dictionary, spellcheck

In macOS I can *Right click -> Learn Spelling* on a word for which the system thinks it is wrongly spelled, but (for me) it is spelled correctly. The word then gets added to my personal dictionary.

However how can I tell macOS to add a specific correction to a wrongly spelled word, the system does not suggest by default? Example: I type **`swiminngly`**, but I want **swimmingly**.(*) macOS (Catalina at least) does not suggest this correction. How can I add *the correction* to my personal dictionary?

---

(*) BTW, the third-party command line speller [`hunspell`](http://hunspell.github.io/) *does* suggest for **`swiminngly`** the word **swimmingly**. It is only the macOS spell system which doesn't do so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do this.
If it thinks the spelling is wrong but has no suggestions, then adding the correct word to the user's Local Dictionary* doesn't seem to help at all.

I have some words that I habitually type incorrectly - not because my brain can't spell, but because my fingers can't spell ;)
One such is browser; for some incomprehensible reason my fingers insist on typing browswer. To combat this, I have added it to my text replacer in System Settings > Keyboard > Text

[image]

It can't cope with plurals, so I need to add it twice.

*which is where words are added if you ask it to Learn Spelling, in `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`

Comment: Great idea to use the text replacer - it works only when you type, not when you review documents you got from somewhere else, but it is better than nothing.